# Problems Opening File In Java Using Default Program

Tags: java

Hi Im trying to open word file using java program. The program gives me the following error"

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method open(File) from the type Desktop
```

I dont know how to fix this. Can you please help me. Thanks. Below is snippet of code.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    List<File> files;
    File startingDirectory = new File("C:/Hello/");
    try {
        files = getFileListing(startingDirectory);
        for (File file : files){
            Desktop.open(file);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

instead

You should also be making a check for `Desktop.isDekstopSupported` to make sure the functionality you are attempting to execute exists

Comment: Nice to have an easy question for a change ;) Glad to be of assist

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate a `Desktop` object first, like this:

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
```

*After* that you can invoke instance methods on the desktop object, like this:

```
d.open(file);
```

In your code, you were trying to invoke the *instance* method `open()` on the *class* `Desktop`, and that won't work. The only methods that can be invoked on a class are *static* methods, all the other methods need to be invoked on an instance of the corresponding class.